React Hot Toast giving 'Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components' error
I am trying to add a Close button in my Toasts using React Hot Toast like the following:
function CustomToaster() {
  return (
    <Toaster
      position="top-center" 
    >
      { (t: Toast) => (
        <ToastBar toast={ t }>
          { ({ icon, message }) => (
            <div>
              <div>
                { icon }
                { message }
              </div>
              { t.type !== 'loading' && (
                <button onClick={ () => toast.remove(t.id) }>
                  X
                </button >
              ) }
            </div>
          ) }
        </ToastBar>
      ) }
    </Toaster>
  );
}

I am putting this in my RootLayout like the following:
export default function RootLayout({ children }: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Link href="/">
           Home
         </Link>
           
         <div>
           { children }
         </div>
         <CustomToaster />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

but I get this error:
Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".

Any ideas on how to pass in that function?

The problem you are facing is due to the use of server-side and client-side components in Next.js. In Next.js 13 and above, when you use Server Components, you cannot pass JavaScript functions to them directly. This problem arises when your component is intended as a server-side component, while you want to use the client-side right (like onClick for a button).
To fix this problem, you need to convert your component to a client-side component. Do this using "use client"; at the top of your component file. This directive causes Next.js to recognize your component as a client-side component.
